# Trigger is invalid, can't find a solution

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I would like to make a trigger which does not allow for a person to have a commission higher than 50% of their salary.

I use the table `emp` which has the columns `empno`, `ename`, `sal` and `comm`.

Here is my code:

```
set define off;
create or replace trigger block_prov
before update or insert on emp
for each row
declare 
  v_sal number;
begin

  if inserting then
    select sal into v_sal from emp where empno = :new.empno;
    if :new.comm > v_sal*0.5 then
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'prov greater than 50% of sal');
    end if;
  end if;

  if updating then
    if :new.comm > :old.sal*0.5 then
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'prov greater than 50% of sal');
    end if;
  end if;
end;
```

The problem is that every time I try to test my code with that line

```
update emp set comm = 700
where empno = 7499;
```

(It should trigger the exception)

the compiler gives me this error message:

```
*04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.
```

Comment: Query the `user_errors` view to see what the actual issues are. Although that looks OK; is that actually the trigger name that's being reported in the error? (Not the issue, but if you're inserting, why would there already be a row in `emp` with that `empno`? And if there was you'd get a mutating table error. Should that just be referring to `:new.sal` instead, and `v_sal` isn't needed?)

Comment: If both salary and commission are stored in the same row it feels simpler to just create a constraint. No idea if it can be really done :)

Comment: Thank you Alex, I figured the error message referred to another trigger, after I deleted it and corrected the error in my trigger you mentioned (the unnecessity of v_sal) it worked like a charm.

Comment: As @ÁlvaroGonzález mentioned, this case would better be addressed by a constraint. Int this case by a `CHECK` constraint. Something like `ALTER TABLE emp ADD CONSTRAINT check_emp_comm_against_sal CHECK(comm <= 0.5 * sal)`.

Answer (score 1):

Although your comment says that *it works like a charm*, consider simplifying it - no need to use local variable or distinguish importing from updating.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_block_prov
  2    before update or insert on emp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if :new.comm > :new.sal * 0.5 then
  6       raise_application_error(-20001, 'prov greater than 50% of sal');
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Updating example:

```
SQL> select ename, sal, comm From emp where ename = 'SMITH';

ENAME             SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- ----------
SMITH             800

SQL> update emp set comm = 500 where ename = 'SMITH';
update emp set comm = 500 where ename = 'SMITH'
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: prov greater than 50% of sal
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BLOCK_PROV", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BLOCK_PROV'


SQL> update emp set comm = 300 where ename = 'SMITH';

1 row updated.

SQL> select ename, sal, comm From emp where ename = 'SMITH';

ENAME             SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- ----------
SMITH             800        300
```

Inserting example:

```
SQL> insert into emp (empno, ename, sal, comm) values (1, 'lf', 1000, null);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into emp (empno, ename, sal, comm) values (2, 'bf', 1000, 700);
insert into emp (empno, ename, sal, comm) values (2, 'bf', 1000, 700)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: prov greater than 50% of sal
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BLOCK_PROV", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BLOCK_PROV'


SQL> insert into emp (empno, ename, sal, comm) values (2, 'bf', 1000, 400);

1 row created.

SQL> select ename, sal, comm From emp where empno in (1, 2);

ENAME             SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- ----------
lf               1000
bf               1000        400

SQL>
```